# what is the right way to set input fields and labels from the properties of the same object in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object with a bunch of properties. Some properties are to be displayed in input elements, some in labels.

So, my code looks like this:

```
  var data = getMyData();
  var propNames = Object.keys(data);
  var i, propName, elem;
  for (i = 0; i < propNames.length; ++i) {
    propName = propNames[i];
    elem = $("#" + propName);
    if (elem.is('input')) {
      elem.val(data[propName]);
    } else {
      elem.html(data[propName]);
    }
  }
```

Is it the right way to do it in jquery? Cause it looks kinda ugly...

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead?

Comment: Did not know about it. If you can move it there I will be OK with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier to store the method name in a variable (`text`/`val`), so that we don't have so much code repetition (the conditional in your code makes for unnecessary repetition).

Also, since you're anyhow using jQuery, you might as well use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). It simplifies all of it into this:

```
$.each(getMyData(), function (key, val)
{
    var el = $("#" + key),
        method = el.is('input') ? 'val' : 'text';

    el[method](val);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pFbSf/

---

If you don't like storing the method name in a variable, use this instead:

```
$.each(getMyData(), function (key, val)
{
    var el = $("#" + key);

    el.is('input') ? el.val(val) : el.text(val);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GQTZv/

---

If you worry about [jQuery not using `hasOwnProperty`](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5499), you can run the check yourself:

```
var data = getMyData();

$.each(data, function (key, val)
{
    if ( ! data.hasOwnProperty(key) ) return;

    var el = $("#" + key);

    el.is('input') ? el.val(val) : el.text(val);
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GQTZv/1/

Comment: Unfortunately `$.each` does not invoke `Object.hasOwnProperty` on the property name before invoking the given callback. On the other hand, I'd like using something like forEach. Is there a safer alternative?

Comment: @mark - You can run the `hasOwnProperty` check yourself. See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can rewrite that for-loop with the jQuery .each() function, which can iterate over any array or object. It takes a callback function, which is given the index (or key) and the value of each item.

In your example it would be something like:

```
jQuery.each(data, function(key, value) {
   elem = jQuery("#" + value);
   if (elem.is('input')) {...
```

Check out the docs for [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to fill either an `input` or a `textarea`, you should be able to replace this with:

```
var data = getMyData();
var propNames = Object.keys(data);

for (i = 0; i < propNames.length; ++i) {
  $("input#"+propNames[i]).val(data[propNames[i]);
  $("textarea#"+propNames[i]).html(data[propNames[i]);
}
```

You might even get away with replacing the two jQuery selectors with:

```
  $("input#"+propNames[i]).val(data[propNames[i]).html(data[propNames[i]);
```

Since `input` elements don't have `innerHTML` and `textarea` elements don't have `val`, this should work as-is. Hackish, but it's succinct.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine to me Mark.  The one thing I would highly advise against is using a new Object prototype method like `Object.keys`, which is only available in IE9+ and other newer browsers. Instead either create the prototype for it before all of your JS (something I actually don't like doing) or instead have a replica work-around global function / namespace method that takes care of it like `function getkeys()` at the bottom.

http://jsfiddle.net/WJ24q/1/

```
for (i = 0; i < propNames.length; ++i) {
    var el = $("#" + propNames[i]),
        _d = data[propNames[i]];

    // you could also use a simple ternary instead of the if/else
    el.is('input') ? el.val(_d) : el.html(_d);
}
```

Function instead of Object.keys:

```
function getKeys (obj){
   var keys = [];
   for(var key in obj){
      keys.push(key);
   }
   return keys;
}
​    ​
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that looks ugly but I don't understand why you need `Object.keys`... You can simplify it a bit with a regular `for...in`:

```
var data = getMyData(), 
    d, $el;
for (d in data) {
  $el = $('#'+ d);
  if ($el.is('input')) {
    $el.val(data[d]);
  } else {
    $el.html(data[d]);
  }
}
```